# Figure of Speech

Tags: word-request

What do we call sentences, like for example "the Hitler of 21st century" and other sentences like that.? What is the literary device/figure of speech used there.?

Comment: The exact word sequence *the Hitler of 20th century* isn't idiomatic. Nor is it a "sentence" in the first place - it's a ***noun phrase*** (that makes no sense, since there was only one Hitler of significance, and he *was* a 20th century figure anyway). You could feasibly say, for example, *North Korea's Kim Jong-un is the Hitler of the **21st** century*, which would be a ***figure of speech*** (of type "comparison"), as  per your title.

Comment: Is the word you're looking for [metaphor](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/metaphor)?

Answer (score 2):

Both comments, from @FumbleFingers and from @stangdon are correct.

Short answer: it is a [metaphor](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/metaphor).

However, in the way expressed, it does not make sense. The only Hitler worth mentioning actually lived in the 20th century.

On the other hand, you can apply *Hitler* to a different time domain and you can use it as a symbol for North Korea's Kim Jong-un:

> North Korea's Kim Jong-un is *the Hitler of the 21st century*